# Averaging multiple train-test splits to estimate the performance with higher variability?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, data

I have a small size data set and I want to assess the effect of a certain type of cases on the overall model performance. For example, is the model biased against people of a certain age group?

Using a single train-test split, the number of cases of a particular type becomes quite small, and I suspect findings may occur due to randomness.

Would it in this scenario make sense to use multiple train-test splits, compute the average performances, and then assess the effects of the particular type of cases after? In other words, improving the variability of the result by including more cases of the particular type.

Comment: You can do [cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) and in each fold make sure you have [stratified randomized folds](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html).

Comment: When would you compute the performance of the models then? I mean… with cross validation, don’t you still need a final, fixed test set to evaluate on, meaning the final evaluation would still be on a low amount of cases?

Comment: It's a good point that the test set would still be on low amount of cases, but you have tried different variations of training and validation set, so you have a good approximation how robust your model is. If the standard deviation of your evaluation metric is high then your model is pretty much guessing but if not, you can be more confident about the robustness of your model. 

It would be nice if you could add the train/test split set sizes (per class) to your question as well.